# DLL Problem: Why I can't read external variable?

Tags: c++, c

I created a Ts3 Plugin in C it should read 2 values and I want to access it external with c++

plugin.c:

```cpp
int isMuted_INPUT = -1, isMuted_OUTPUT = -1;
void ts3plugin_onUpdateClientEvent(uint64 serverconnectionhandlerID, anyID clientID, anyID invokerID, const char* invokerName, const char* invokerUniqueIdentifier) {


    if (ts3Functions.getClientSelfVariableAsInt(serverconnectionhandlerID, CLIENT_INPUT_MUTED, &isMuted_INPUT) == ERROR_ok) {
        printf("[MuteStatusHelper] Mute STATUS INPUT: %i\n", isMuted_INPUT);
    }
    if (ts3Functions.getClientSelfVariableAsInt(serverconnectionhandlerID, CLIENT_OUTPUT_MUTED, &isMuted_OUTPUT) == ERROR_ok) {
        printf("[MuteStatusHelper] Mute STATUS OUTPUT: %i\n", isMuted_OUTPUT);
    }

}

int  getMuteStatus_INPUT() {
    return isMuted_INPUT;
 }
int getMuteStatus_OUTPUT() {
   return isMuted_OUTPUT;
 }
```

plugin.h:

```cpp
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl getMuteStatus_INPUT(void);
__declspec(dllexport) int __cdecl getMuteStatus_OUTPUT(void);
```

It should return 0 or 1 but it returns -1
changing it for test pupose to

```cpp
int  getMuteStatus_INPUT() {
    return 345;
 }
```

is returning 345

main.cpp

```cpp
typedef HRESULT(CALLBACK* LPFNDLLFUNC1)();

int main()
{

    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamSpeak 3 Client\\plugins\\MuteStatusHelper.dll");
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hGetProcIDDLL), "getMuteStatus_INPUT");
    typedef int(__cdecl * pICFUNC)();
    pICFUNC MyFunction;
    MyFunction = pICFUNC(lpfnGetProcessID);
    int Result = MyFunction();
    std::cout << "INPUT WERT: " << Result << std::endl;
    //FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have any evidence that `ts3plugin_onUpdateClientEvent` is called?

Comment: Most likely a mistake elsewhere.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks. Yes when I open ts3 console it prints the mute status correctly

Comment: How do you call your function? Do you use another instance of your library than the one used by TS3?

Comment: I have linked the .lib and using the same .dll, TS3 is only using the .dll

Comment: I've added the main.cpp

Comment: Missing extern “C” in your header?

Comment: No it is not missing

Comment: I would expect to have 2 different instances of the lib. One ist instantiated by TS3 and the other by your main.cpp. shared libs share code but each instance has independent set of data.

Comment: ok good to know, how is it possible to use the same instance?